# Swift, Styling two navigation bar with code

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uinavigationbar

I'm developing an app on which requires two navigation bar at the top. I was planning on inputting custom fonts for both titles, and I did it by code in my View Controller's `viewDidLoad` like so,

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SignPainter-HouseScript", size: 30)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Doing this, both my navigation bar's title changed, which is not what I intended it to do. How do I customize each navigation bar separately in one view controller, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you use appearance proxy, it will apply global settings.**

To get different style for two different object, you have change the same property for a specific object.

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SignPainter-HouseScript", size: 30)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]`

Wrire above code in `viewDidLoad:` of your first viewController.
It will change the `titleTextAttributes` of first navigation controller.

Similarly get object of other navigationController and  change the same property.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you for explaining in detail!! Have a great day Mr.

Answer (score 0):

you can set custom navigation title view like this:

    `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = "a custom UIView"
    }`

so that every viewController have their own custom title view.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! However, it wasn't that simple. The accepted answer is more complete. But thanks again!